# Request payload is [Object Object] in the AJAX post request triggered

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object, post

I am sending a ajax request with the following data. The data here is an object and I intend to send an object itself (not stringified JSON). But when I see the request in browser, the request payload is displayed as [object object] even though I am sending a project JS object.

```
let emailIdForAPICall = { "email": "abc@gmail.com"};

$.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
           url: gigyaServlet,
           data: {    
             'profile': emailIdForAPICall,
           }
    })
```

Once the above API call is triggered, the payload looks like below -
[image]

Tried using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(emailIdForAPICall)) but it still did not work.

Whats worrying is, same type of request works a different site properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let emailIdForAPICall = {
    "email": "abc@gmail.com"
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: gigyaServlet,
    data: JSON.stringify({  //stringify your obj
        'profile': emailIdForAPICall,
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',  // add contentType
})
```

Comment: The data to be sent with request should be an object. I cannot stringify it. And the contentType is set as application/json

Answer (score 0):

Ramya Shivu your request is from data or JSON. if JSON then please pass contentType: 'application/json',in header & if it is  form data

```
let emailIdForAPICall = { "email": "abc@gmail.com"};

 $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
               url: gigyaServlet,
               data: JSON.stringify({  //stringify your obj
            'profile': emailIdForAPICall,
        })
        })
```

Comment: Hi, I have added content: application/json. and the requirement is not to stringify the object.